# Different 100% height of table in Chrome/IE and FireFox

Tags: html, css, html-table

The problem is, that all of elements (main container, table container and table itself) must have 100% height. Table itself has slightly smaller size in Chrome and IE, than in Firefox, which causes a small gap between .table-container and table borders.

Do somebody know how to fix this? I've spent almost all day for this, and can't simply find a solution. Would be grateful for any help.

Here is a link for fiddle with my current problem: [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEeNH/6/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="buttons">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>b</td>
                    <td>c</td>
                    <td>d</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>aa</td>
                    <td>bb</td>
                    <td>cc</td>
                    <td>dd</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>aaa</td>
                    <td>bbb</td>
                    <td>ccc</td>
                    <td>ddd</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
html, body, .container, .table-container, table
{
    height: 100%;
}

.container
{
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.table-container
{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.buttons
{
    height: 30px;
}

.buttons div
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

thead td, tbody td
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}
```

**Update**: added padding and negative margin for .table-container
**Update2**: added border-spacing and border-collapse to an example. Still not working properly.
**Update3**: Now it works here, which means, that i couldn't fully reproduce my bug to show it to you :( But in general, the problem is, that the height of 5x5 table in Chrome is less from FF on 22px, which is 22px gap between table container and a table itself. Each cell has around 4px + to table height in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be the border spacing on the table.

Apply this CSS to the table element:

```
border-spacing: 0;
```

Comment: Nope, added those two into fiddle and code here. Didn't helped

Comment: Border-spacing is not valid when the border-collapse is set to 'collapse' it is only used when border-collapse is set to separate!

Comment: So for THIS example, you're right, SpAm. But trouble still persists and i think that i'm forced to figure it out by myself :) Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that

```
width: 100%;
```

does not work the exactly the same way as

```
height: 100%;
```

does.

While width: 100% grabs 100% of the parent's width even if there has not been an explicit setting of that width, height: 100% works only on elements whose parents have a fixed height.

Simply speaking, %-width applies dynamically, while %-height applies to static parents container's heights.

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I was having the same problems with different 100% height of table for Chrome and Firefox. The fix is to add a border the table. You can just add border-bottom as well and it won't actually show up in Chrome, but will fix the height issue.

```
table
{
    **border-bottom: 1px solid black;**
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```